# jquery script that used to work is not working with jquery 1.4.2

Tags: jquery

... and i cant figure out why.

The script is following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://path/to/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function openMediaPlayer() {
                $('#flashMovie').animate({'height':'333px'});
            }
            function closeMediaPlayer() {
                $('#flashMovie').animate({'height':'80px'});
            }
            jQuery(function($){
                $('#videoholder').bind('mouseenter', function(){
                    openMediaPlayer();
                });
                $('#videoholder').bind('mouseleave', function(){
                    closeMediaPlayer();
                });
            });
</script>
<div id="videoholder" style="height:80px;width:412px;">
<object width="412" height="80" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flashMovie" name="flashMovie" style="height: 80px;" data="http://path/to/Player.swf"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="bgcolor" value="#666666"><param name="allowFullscreen" value="true"><param name="flashvars" value="playlistURL=http://path/to/Player/data/playlist.xml"></object>
</div>
```

pure and simple resizing flash object. It worked with older(1.3.2) jquery verision. The animate just does not work.

Can anyone tell me what i should change to get it working again?

Alan.

Comment: none, whatsoever. If i put alert("here") before $('#flashMovie').animate({'height':'333px'});
, it fires. If i put it after. it fails silently.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's being included correctly? If you view source on the page and click on the `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` does it come up?

Comment: Compare http://jsfiddle.net/GHg4w/1/ which uses jQuery 1.3.2 which works with http://jsfiddle.net/GHg4w/2/ which uses jQuery 1.4.2 and doesn't work.

Comment: Im sure the path is correct. the jquery file does come up and like i said - if i put alert before animate, it fires. It wouldnt fire if jquery is imporperly included. 

Im not sure whom Blair's comment is meant for.

Comment: Comment was meant for everyone. First link show it working, second link shows it not working. Only change is the jQuery version.

Comment: Guess i should report it as bug to jquery then...

Comment: Must be a bug. Only seems to occur with the `<object>` tag. I get this error: `TypeError: Result of expression 'queue' [undefined] is not an object. jquery.js:1177`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no error because jQuery catches and throws away event handler errors in response to `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` (line 2170 in 1.4.2). *Bad jQuery!* Using `mouseover`/`mouseout` instead allows you to see the error.

Which is: ‘queue is undefined’ on line 1177. This is caused by the previous call to `queue()` failing, because the attempt to set the `fxqueue` data item on the `<object>` fails. (But instead of raising an error to flag the failure, it silently returns `undefined`. *Bad jQuery!*)

jQuery 1.4.2 fails to set `data()` on `<object>` (where 1.3.2 succeeds) because it deliberately won't: it checks the `jQuery.noData` variable which tells it that `<object>` elements can't have arbitrary (‘expando’) properties set on them, and jQuery's `data()` mechanism, and hence animation-queuing is dependent on this facility. *Bad jQuery!*

Traditionally browsers have had trouble with expandos on `<object>`, but specifically for the case of Flash, it *does* actually work in most modern browsers (even if it's pretty bad practice). So you could try telling jQuery to shut up and allow you to animate plugin elements by saying:

```
jQuery.noData= {};
```

at some point before calling `animate`.

Answer (score 3):

From jQuery 1.4.2, line 993

```
// The following elements throw uncatchable exceptions if you
// attempt to add expando properties to them.
noData: {
    "embed": true,
    "object": true,
    "applet": true
},
```

When attempting to set the elements `data()` on line 1002, jQuery appears to first check to see if it has one of the three elements listed above. If so, it returns immediately.

```
data: function( elem, name, data ) {
    if ( elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()] ) {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

I won't pretend to be a very knowledgeable "under the hood" guy, but I think this may be the root of the problem, and appears to be intentional.

---

**EDIT:**

The solution **bobince** gave to override jQuery's `noData`, would seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

'Can anyone tell me what i should change to get it working again?'

Change your 'flashMovie' to height 100% widht 100% and animate on videoholder, don`t think it will work in ie tho... it seams to be working, but i cant test it any further you ll have to see. g2g

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error at line number 1899 [jquery1.7.2 uncompressed]. I replaced the following and it worked.

From:

```
var match = jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()];
```

to:

```
var match = jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toString().toLowerCase()];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this ticket's answer:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10776