# Onclick change flash.width

Tags: jquery, css, flash

can flash width be changed like divs in example below

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bartula/3Myhx/29/)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the width off a flash object by doing

```
$('.scribblar').width('100%');
```

But Im pretty sure animate will not work with flash objects though :(

If you really wanted an effect you could make the flash object the width you want using the function above, then append an absolute div over the top the size you have increased then do some effects on that but its alot off faff, and may not give you the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks, for help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually change the attribute width with something like.

```
$('#flash_scribblar ').attr('width', '100%');
```

Use [.attr() doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my comment,

I have found [**JQUERY ANIMATE NOT WORKING WITH FLASH OBJECT**](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6619) by using google.com

In above ticket it is mentioned that it works fine with **jquery 1.3.2**, but is not working with jquery1.4.2.

Your Fiddle doens't work because it is using latest jquery but it is working with **jQuery 1.3.2**

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/3Myhx/32/)

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949478/jquery-script-that-used-to-work-is-not-working-with-jquery-1-4-2) which have mentioned following:

> Traditionally browsers have had trouble with expandos on `<object>`, but specifically for the case of Flash, it does actually work in most modern browsers (even if it's pretty bad practice). So you could try telling jQuery to shut up and allow you to animate plugin elements by saying:
>
> jQuery.noData= {};

Answer (score 0):

It works when wrapping the div around the object and altering the widht (or whatever your values are....). If you want different alignment, just position them differently, but the change of the width is there. Additionally, `param` should be closed with `/>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3Myhx/33/